# Find max(list) in python which is less than specified value

Tags: python, list, max

```
x = [2,4,34,35,36,37]
```

if transmax = 36 the o/p = 36
if transmax = 10 then o/p = 4 (because this is the maximum within the boundary 10.

I have return the below function but it get timed out sometime.. any other optimal way available?

```
def rangemaxhouse(transmax):
    return(max(i for i in x if i<= transmax))
```

Comment: What you have is how it's done.

Comment: You are not passing `x` as a param there.

Comment: Well if you have sorted data, avoid using list comprehension. Traverse the list only till you dont get your desired result and then break.

Answer (score 1):

That's the canonical way to do it. In theory it could go ever-so-slightly faster if you use `filter` with a built-in function implemented in C, but not much:

```
from future_builtins import filter  # Only on Py2, for generator based filter

def rangemaxhouse(transmax):
    return max(filter(transmax.__ge__, x))
```

As it happens, in this case in local testing on 3.5.2, it still runs slower, with no scaling benefits; the generator expression is strictly faster (there is a reason `map` and `filter` are generally discouraged; the times they win are limited and not particularly predictable).